# getting invalid number when aggregating varchar using to_number

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, oracle-sqldeveloper, aggregate-functions

I have the below query

```
select avg(to_number(pst_adm_scr)) from dmereg01.tst_scr
```

I keep getting the error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

The field is originally a varchar with numeric values (scores)

Comment: At least one of the string values cannot be converted to a number. You might think that's not the case because you can query the table without the `avg()`, but when you do that you might just be fetching the first page (e.g. 50 rows) of data, which happen to all be OK. You can use `to_number()` with the default on conversion error extension, or `validate_conversion()`, to identify problem values.

Comment: Yeap, you have some sort of string or ```NULL``` value in that column.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your database version (which you haven't specified), you may be able to use the ON CONVERSION ERROR component of TO_NUMBER to ignore the invalid values

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('-' DEFAULT null ON CONVERSION ERROR)
from dual;
```